# How to download a set of data which includes images and videos using work manager along with progress detail?

Tags: android, android-workmanager, android-download-manager

In my Android App, there is a list of some objects which is fetched from the server. Each of this object JSON contains some textual data along with a set of image and video URLs. The use case is, user can download this whole data from a single click and would be stored in a local storage.

I am trying different ways to make this happen using Work manager but I am not able to find a way to track this download progress as a whole to show in the UI as there are multiple files being downloaded. Also, how can I make sure if the whole data of that specific object is downloaded completely from the downloaded files in case any of them failed?

Comment: Have you considered `DownloadManager`?  It comes with a notification that displays progress

Comment: Yes, I considered it, but I need the download to work in background as well even if the user has killed/terminated the app after starting the download. And Download manager will display a separate notifications for progress for each file being downloaded.

Comment: What about Broadcast receiver to trace download state changes? Still you will have to implement how to calculate progress.

Answer (score 2):

> track this download progress as a whole to show in the UI as there are multiple files being downloaded.

In old days we need to use the `ForegroundService`, but now it's available on `WorkManager`. For using `WorkManager` with "ForegroundService" feature, check out these articles:

- [WorkManager: use foreground service for executing long running tasks](https://medium.com/@sdex/run-worker-as-foreground-service-b607819fd263)
- [Use WorkManager for immediate background execution](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/use-workmanager-for-immediate-background-execution-a57db502603d)
- [Support for long-running workers](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/long-running#long-running-kotlin)

---

> how can I make sure if the whole data of that specific object is downloaded completely from the downloaded files in case any of them failed?

You can do null check on certain field.

Comment: In Android 12 the approach using setForeground / setForegroundAsync is unreliable. As desribed in the docs https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker#getForegroundInfoAsync(): "Calling setForegroundAsync will fail with an IllegalStateException when the process is subject to foreground service restrictions. Consider using WorkRequest.Builder.setExpedited(OutOfQuotaPolicy) and getForegroundInfoAsync() instead."  However getForegroundAsync allows to return the notification only once as it returns `ListenableFuture`. Can we update the notification in this case anyhow?